# How to execute sql file on Redshift

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have an SQL file which has few temporary creation scripts and few insert scripts.

We want to execute this SQL file on Redshift using AWS services.

Comment: from your client, use psql just as if you were using postgres, you can use aws ec2 instance as a client.

Comment: You can use any compatible JDBC/ODBC SQL client. See: [Connecting to Clusters from Client Tools and Code - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-via-client-tools.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've found that you need to use Python for this since Redshift is based on Postgres 8. You can build a psql client from Postgres source for 8 which will also work.

Below is a py example I used:

Requirements:

- Python
- [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html)

Code for your file like mypythonfile.py

```
import sys
import psycopg2

con=psycopg2.connect("dbname=dev host=" + sys.argv[1] + " port=5439 user=redshift password=" + sys.argv[2])
con.set_isolation_level(0)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("create database myedw with owner redshift")
cur.close()
con.close()
print("Database created")

con=psycopg2.connect("dbname=myedw host=" + sys.argv[1] + " port=5439 user=redshift password=" + sys.argv[2])
con.set_isolation_level(0)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute(open("edw-schemas.sql", "r").read())
con.commit()
cur.execute(open("edw-master.sql", "r").read())
print("EDW structure created")
print("Done")
```

You can then execute the script as follows:

```
python mypythonfile.py {redshift host} {password}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Client provided by AWS for Redshift can be the starting point. Enabling Access to the EditorAmazonRedshiftQueryEditor is the way to go [AWS Query Editor](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor.html)
For advanced IDE needs this can be referred [IDE](https://www.quora.com/Which-IDE-is-the-best-to-connect-to-AWS-Redshift). Best!

Comment: I find the query editor really painful to use. They create a tab for each SQL statement so if you have many statements, no way to tell if one failed except by clicking each tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple Python script running on an EC2 instance (or any other server) to establish a JDBC connection to Redshift (using [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/)) and then execute the queries in your `.SQL` file.

Answer (score 0):

I came across similar task and resolved using below few lines of code. You will need to install [redshift-connector](https://pypi.org/project/redshift-connector/) package provided by AWS.

```
# import packages
import redshift_connector
import pandas as pd

# Configure database credentials
conn = redshift_connector.connect(
    host={redshift_host},
    database={database_name},
    port={port_number_integer},
    user={redshift_user},
    password={redshift_user}
)

# Create a Cursor object
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Execute script
cursor.execute(open("test_script.sql", "r").read())

# Convert results into Pandas dataframe
result: pd.DataFrame = cursor.fetch_dataframe()

# Show results
print(result)
```

You can refer this [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/python-connect-examples.html) for detail explanation of use of this package.