# Executing an SQL file on Redshift via the CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

We have an SQL file that we would like to run on our Redshift cluster, we're already aware that this is possible via `psql` as described in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65730986/how-to-run-a-sql-statements-sequentially) and [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53479092/how-to-execute-sql-file-on-redshift). However, we were wondering whether this was possible using the [Redshift Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html)?

We looked through the documentation but were unable to find anything apart from [`batch-execute-statement`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/redshift-data/batch-execute-statement.html) which takes a space delimited list of SQL statements. We're happy to resort to this but would prefer a method of running a file directly against the cluster.

Also, we'd like to parameterise the file as well, can this be done?

#### Our Current Attempt

This is what we've tried so far:

```bash
PARAMETERS="[\
    {\"name\": \"param1\", \"value\": \"${PARAM1}\"}, \
    {\"name\": \"param2\", \"value\": \"${PARAM2}\"}, \
    {\"name\": \"param3\", \"value\": \"${PARAM3}\"}, \
    {\"name\": \"param4\", \"value\": \"${PARAM4}\"}, \
    {\"name\": \"param5\", \"value\": \"${PARAM5}\"}, \
    {\"name\": \"param6\", \"value\": \"${PARAM6}\"}\
    ]"

SCRIPT_SQL=$(tr -d '\n' <./sql/script.sql)

AWS_RESPONSE=$(aws redshift-data execute-statement \
    --region $AWS_REGION \
    --cluster-identifier $CLUSTER_IDENTIFIER \
    --sql "$SCRIPT_SQL" \
    --parameters "$PARAMETERS" \
    --database public \
    --secret $CREDENTIALS_ARN)
```

Where all undeclared variables are variables set earlier in the script.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused. Redshift Data API is a REST API which expects you to send a request and it executes the query against your cluster (or serverless). Typical usage might be like using a Lambda Function to connect to your Redshift environment, and execute queries from there. You can load your file into Lambda, decompose and send the commands one by one if you like. And of course, you can parametrise anything within that Lambda. But for the Redshift Data API to work, it needs to be request - response type of operation.

And please note it is an async API.

Comment: I've now changed company so unfortunately I no longer work on Redshift. However, the original aim of this question was to look for a method to execute a parameterised file using CLI tooling. The idea behind this was to execute DDL statements on startup using a script